# LINQPad 4 Error in Downloading More Samples

Tags: linqpad

I am having this error when I try to download LINQPad sample libraries: Error while unpacking sample queries: C:\Documents and Settings[user]\Local Settings\Temp\LINQPad\TempSampleQueries849247.zip is not a valid zip file.

I use LinqPad 4 (installed version). The weird thing is I also have LINQPad 4 (licensed standalone executable) at home and I didn't encounter any problems in downloading. Do I need to have license to be able to download the sample files?

Edit:

I am also having problems in activating my LINQPad. The error says: Unable to contact licensing server: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. I pretty much sure I'm not using any proxies. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain you're not going through a proxy? I don't see any other way you could be getting a 407 error. Entering the proxy username/password into LINQPad's proxy dialog (Edit | Preferences | Updates) should fix it.

If you're still unable to proceed, you can perform an offline activation [here](https://www.linqpad.net/licensing/offline.aspx) and download the sample libraries via a web browser [here](http://www.linqpad.net/RichClient/SampleLibraries.aspx). After downloading a samples zip file, click 'Download more samples' and type in the local file path to import it.

Comment: I double checked and I was going through a proxy (my bad, hehe). After manually setting the proxy, I was able to activate my license and download the samples like magic. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Remember to flag this as an answer if helpful!

Comment: including *.dll's and *.exe's in the samples will prevent the download through many company proxys and download content checkers.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to prevent the proxy 407 authentication needed error when licensing or updating Linqpad: Add the following to Linqpad's config file

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```